# Unable to connect to any secured Wi-Fi that requires a password but can connect to unsecured Wi-Fi without issue

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I’m using Windows 7 Home Premium on my Sony Vaio laptop and I’ve recently encountered a problem where I can’t connect to any Wi-Fi network that requires a password despite being able to see the Wi-Fi network.

But if there are no passwords required the connection is okay.

This happened after I downloaded a game and after installing [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com) I don’t know what really has happened but I think that the two events are linked together.

Comment: I would suggest removing the current wireless network device using your Device Manager, then installing it again using the latest available drivers.

Comment: " can’t connect to any Wi-Fi network that requires a password" more details please. "Can't" does not tell us much.

Comment: The router is visible and when I try to connect to it I write the password then it hangs on " Connecting to (SSID) " and doesn't proceed

Comment: Please do as suggested above - reinstall the WiFi device drivers and software - and no, the events you mentioned aren't related.

Comment: I've tried that but nothing happened ,

Comment: Is the wireless network card driver from your laptop manufacturer or Microsoft?
We can use the driver from your laptop manufacturer, and try to replace the version of the wireless network card driver.

Comment: Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN this is my built-in driver software so I think it's manufactured by Intel , My laptop is Sony Vaio VPCCA 15FA

Comment: What is  Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software and should I update it?